# Finding the solution to differential equation dilemma.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, differential-algebra

Suppose $\ddot{x_1} =\frac{k(x_2-2x_1)}{3m}$ and $\ddot{x_2}=\frac{k(x_1-x_2)}{2m}$ now how do I solve for $x_1 $ and $x_2$ where $x_2 $& $x_1$ aren't independent of each other ie can't be held constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Assuming you know the Laplace transform method we have

$$
s^2
\left(\begin{array}{c}
X_1(s)\\
X_2(s)
\end{array}
\right) -\left(\begin{array}{c}
s \dot x_1(0)+x_1(0)\\
s \dot x_2(0)+x_2(0)
\end{array}
\right)= K \left(\begin{array}{c}
X_1(s)\\
X_2(s)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

or

$$
\left(I_2 s^2-K\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
X_1(s)\\
X_2(s)
\end{array}
\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
s \dot x_1(0)+x_1(0)\\
s \dot x_2(0)+x_2(0)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

then

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
X_1(s)\\
X_2(s)
\end{array}
\right) = \left(I_2 s^2-K\right)^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
s \dot x_1(0)+x_1(0)\\
s \dot x_2(0)+x_2(0)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Here

$$
I_2 s^2-K = \left(\begin{array}{cc}s^2-k_{11}& -k_{12}\\ -k_{21}& s^2-k_{22}\end{array}\right)
$$

and

$$
\left(I_2 s^2-K\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{(s^2-k_{11})(s^2-k_{22})+k_{12}k_{21}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}s^2-k_{22}& k_{12}\\  k_{21}& s^2-k_{11}\end{array}\right)
$$

and

$$
K = \left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{2k}{3m}& \frac{k}{3m}\\ \frac{k}{2m}& -\frac{k}{2m}\end{array}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a 1st order ODE through $x_3 := \dot{x_1}$ and $x_4 := \dot{x_2}$. Then let $y = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T$ so that
$$\dot{y} = \begin{bmatrix} 0_{2\times 2} & I_{2\times 2}\\ \frac{k}{6m} \begin{bmatrix} -4 & 2 \\ 3 & -3\end{bmatrix} & 0_{2\times 2}  \end{bmatrix}y := Ay$$
Then use Jordan Normal from to write 
$$A = P^{-1} D P$$
Where $D$ is diagonal. Then change variables again so that
$$\bar{y} := P \bar{y}$$ solves
$$\dot{\bar{y}} = D \bar{y}$$
Then
$$\bar{y}_i = e^{ d_i t}$$
with $d_i$ the possible complex entries of $\bar{D}$ and convert back to $x_i$'s.